# Win32 equivalent of getuid()

Tags: c++, windows

I'm in the process of porting a C++ library from Linux to Windows, and am having problems with getuid(), which is not supported in Windows.

Any ideas what I can use in its place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieves the name of the user associated with the current thread with [GetUserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724432(VS.85).aspx) :

```
// ANSI version    
string GetWindowsUserNameA()
    {
        char buffer[UNLEN + 1] = {0};
        DWORD buffer_len = UNLEN + 1;
        if (!::GetUserNameA(buffer, & buffer_len))
        {
            // error handling
        }

        return string(buffer);
    }
```

Comment: GetUserName() works on every version of windows, you can't trust minimal versions listed on MSDN

Comment: @Anders Are you shure it works on Win32s platform too?

Comment: @user877329: No, not sure about that, maybe I should have said every version since Win95.

Comment: Pay attention to edit #3: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1594788/3 it make the above code invalid. buffer_len is required to be initialized.

Comment: `getuid` returns an integer, why is this returning a string? did I missed something?

Answer (score 5):

The Windows equivilent is actually the user's SID.  You can get this by using the "[GetTokenInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446671(VS.85).aspx)" call and querying for the TokenUser information class.

To call GetTokenInformation, you need a handle to the users token, which you can get by calling OpenProcessToken (or OpenThreadToken if you're impersonating someone).

Comment: I believe this gets you information about the SID being used to run the process, so it's essentially equivalent to `geteuid()` rather than `getuid()`.

Answer (score 3):

Windows' closest equivalent of a UID is (probably) a SID. `GetUserName` followed by `LookupAccountName` should get you the user's SID.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sddl.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <memory>

struct heap_delete
{
    typedef LPVOID pointer;
    void operator()(LPVOID p)
    {
        ::HeapFree(::GetProcessHeap(), 0, p);
    }
};
typedef std::unique_ptr<LPVOID, heap_delete> heap_unique_ptr;

struct handle_delete
{
    typedef HANDLE pointer;
    void operator()(HANDLE p)
    {
        ::CloseHandle(p);
    }
};
typedef std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, handle_delete> handle_unique_ptr;

typedef uint32_t uid_t;

BOOL GetUserSID(HANDLE token, PSID* sid)
{
    if (
        token == nullptr || token == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
        || sid == nullptr
        )
    {
        SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);
        return FALSE;
    }
    DWORD tokenInformationLength = 0;
    ::GetTokenInformation(
        token, TokenUser, nullptr, 0, &tokenInformationLength);
    if(GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    heap_unique_ptr data(
        ::HeapAlloc(
            ::GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,     
            tokenInformationLength));
    if (data.get() == nullptr)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    BOOL getTokenInfo = ::GetTokenInformation(
        token, TokenUser, data.get(),
        tokenInformationLength, &tokenInformationLength);
    if (! getTokenInfo)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    PTOKEN_USER pTokenUser = (PTOKEN_USER)(data.get());
    DWORD sidLength = ::GetLengthSid(pTokenUser->User.Sid);
    heap_unique_ptr sidPtr(
        ::HeapAlloc(
            GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sidLength));
    PSID sidL = (PSID)(sidPtr.get());
    if (sidL == nullptr)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    BOOL copySid = ::CopySid(sidLength, sidL, pTokenUser->User.Sid);
    if (! copySid)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (!IsValidSid(sidL))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    *sid = sidL;
    sidPtr.release();
    return TRUE;
}

uid_t GetUID(HANDLE token)
{
    PSID sid = nullptr;
    BOOL getSID = GetUserSID(token, &sid);
    if (! getSID || ! sid)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    heap_unique_ptr sidPtr((LPVOID)(sid));
    LPWSTR stringSid = nullptr;
    BOOL convertSid = ::ConvertSidToStringSidW(
        sid, &stringSid);
    if (! convertSid)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    uid_t ret = -1;
    LPCWSTR p = ::wcsrchr(stringSid, L'-');
    if (p && ::iswdigit(p[1]))
    {
        ++p;
        ret = ::_wtoi(p);
    }
    ::LocalFree(stringSid);
    return ret;
}

uid_t getuid()
{
    HANDLE process = ::GetCurrentProcess();
    handle_unique_ptr processPtr(process);
    HANDLE token = nullptr;
    BOOL openToken = ::OpenProcessToken(
        process, TOKEN_READ|TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE, &token);
    if (! openToken)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    handle_unique_ptr tokenPtr(token);
    uid_t ret = GetUID(token);
    return ret;
}

uid_t geteuid()
{
    HANDLE process = ::GetCurrentProcess();
    HANDLE thread = ::GetCurrentThread();
    HANDLE token = nullptr;
    BOOL openToken = ::OpenThreadToken(
        thread, TOKEN_READ|TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE, FALSE, &token);
    if (! openToken && ::GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_TOKEN)
    {
        openToken = ::OpenThreadToken(
            thread, TOKEN_READ|TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE, TRUE, &token);
        if (! openToken && ::GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_TOKEN)
        {
            openToken = ::OpenProcessToken(
                process, TOKEN_READ|TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE, &token);
        }
    }
    if (! openToken)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    handle_unique_ptr tokenPtr(token);
    uid_t ret = GetUID(token);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    uid_t uid = getuid();
    uid_t euid = geteuid();
    std::cout
        << "uid: "  << std::setbase(10) << uid  << std::endl
        << "euid: " << std::setbase(10) << euid << std::endl
        << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that the answer given by [Larry Osterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/761503/larry-osterman) was very helpful. It got me started in the correct direction.

Comment: Great answer! However, I miss some modern code: raw pointers, raw arrays, etc. they make me sad.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Microsoft's recommendations on porting with the [Interix (also known as Services for UNIX 3.0)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463206.aspx) library.  Overkill for what you want though.

Answer (score 0):

in DotNet - Environment.UserName

Comment: The question specifies C++.  Unless OP is willing to move to C++/CLI, this doesn't help.

Answer (score -1):

The right api is SHGetUID(), exported from Shell

Comment: I can find no evidence any function by that name exists in the Win32 API